# Error in an reacs app when I try to use getItem from localStorage

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I created a react component, to login into an app. When I try to get the name from localStorage and use it to add it as a string to a login navbar I get an error.

In My component is have this code:

`const auth = localStorage.getItem("user");`

and in navbar if I add this line:

`<li> <Link onClick={logout} to="/signup"> Logout ({JSON.parse(auth).name}) </Link> </li>`

more specifically:

`{JSON.parse(auth).name}`

I get this error:

"undefined" is not valid JSON SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON

Answer (score 1):

This means the user doesn't exist. You can check it by using this code:

```js
const auth = localStorage.getItem("user");
const name = auth ? JSON.parse(auth).name : "";
```

The call the name const like this:

```js
<li>
  <Link onClick={logout} to="/signup">
    Logout ({name})
  </Link>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In provided code, auth is undefined, which means there's no item in localStorage with the key "user". You can try this code:-

```
const auth = localStorage.getItem("user");

const userName = auth ? JSON.parse(auth).name : null;

<li>
  <Link onClick={logout} to="/signup"> Logout ({userName}) </Link>
</li>
```

By applying this code,even if auth is undefined, the code won't attempt to parse it, and you won't encounter a "SyntaxError".

Comment: Not work. When I delete: const userName = auth ? JSON.parse(auth).name : null; and ({userName}), the code works. Also before those modifications, then I delete in my code ({ JSON.parse(auth).name}), the app works.

Comment: then you have to add some logging to understand the state of auth and why it might be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, both Akeel Ahmed Qureshi and Adam Basha have right. I make a mistake when I use localStorage.setItem function. Tnanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).